# python run from C# does not create .txt files

Tags: c#, python, python-2.7, visual-studio

i wrote a python script that creates 3 .txt files which are used to display results. When i tried to run the script from C# in visual studio 2017 it runs the script and gives me the correct output that should but then the python script does not create any .txt files. Ive tried running the same script directly from cmd and works perfectly and the same goes for py-charm. I've also looked in the debug folder of the visual studio project but there are no files in there. Any advice, thanks in advance :D

```
 public void run_script()
    {
        string scriptPath = @"C:\-\script.py";

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Python27\python.exe", scriptPath);
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
        p.Close();
```

Comment: It's likely that the files are actually created successfully (assuming no errors are actually thrown) but they are located in the folder that your C# project is executed from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite likely, that the files are generated correcly, but not in the location you expect them.

Try either setting the `WorkingDirectory` of your process

```
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\path\to\output";
```

or setting the full path for your output files in the python script.

Answer (score 0):

To make things more simple, use IronPython.
It's a free, open source library, can get it from nuget.

or by nuget console :

```
Install-Package IronPython -Version 2.7.8.1
```

to run the file :
add these namespaces :

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
```

then simply :

```
ScriptEngine pScript = Python.CreateEngine();
 pScript.ExecuteFile(@"yourPythonFile.py");
```